# How does using String#between? with DateTime objects work in Rails?

Tags: ruby, string, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5

Using **Ruby 2.3.2**, **Rails 5.0.0.1**

**In Ruby console**

```
2.3.2 :001 > date_time_str = "2015-01-08 08:17:15 UTC"
 => "2015-01-08 08:17:15 UTC" 
2.3.2 :002 > date_time_range_start = "2015-01-08 08:16:15 UTC"
 => "2015-01-08 08:16:15 UTC" 
2.3.2 :003 > date_time_range_end = "2015-01-08 08:20:15 UTC"
 => "2015-01-08 08:20:15 UTC" 

2.3.2 :008 > require 'date'
 => true 

2.3.2 :009 > date_time_str.between?(DateTime.parse(date_time_range_start), DateTime.parse(date_time_range_end))

ArgumentError: comparison of String with DateTime failed
    from (irb):9:in `between?'
    from (irb):9
    from /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I expected the above behaviour as I was attempting to compare a `String` instance with a `DateTime` instance. However when I attempt the same in rails console it returns expected result as shown below.

**In Rails console**

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
2.3.2 :001 > date_time_str = "2015-01-08 08:17:15 UTC"
 => "2015-01-08 08:17:15 UTC" 
2.3.2 :002 > date_time_range_start = "2015-01-08 08:16:15 UTC"
 => "2015-01-08 08:16:15 UTC" 
2.3.2 :003 > date_time_range_end = "2015-01-08 08:20:15 UTC"
 => "2015-01-08 08:20:15 UTC" 
2.3.2 :004 > date_time_str.between?(DateTime.parse(date_time_range_start), DateTime.parse(date_time_range_end))
 => true 
2.3.2 :005 > date_time_str_2 = "2015-01-08 08:21:15 UTC"
 => "2015-01-08 08:21:15 UTC" 
2.3.2 :006 > date_time_str_2.between?(DateTime.parse(date_time_range_end), DateTime.parse(r_e))
 => false
```

Can anybody please help me understand what Rails does internally to make the above work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#<=>` in ruby tries to compare itself to the other object. If the other object is incomparable (not a string), then the implementation for string specifically ([c-source here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0555bd8435d352a24bab1e03a7879b9abcc34b88/string.c#L3399)) compares the other object to the receiving string.

In other words, `"str" <=> obj` is equivalent to

```
if obj.is_a?(String)
  # compare bytes
elsif obj.respond_to?(:to_str)
  obj = obj.to_str
  # compare bytes
else
  # a few safety checks
  -1 * (obj <=> "str")
end
```

Now we have `"str" <=> obj` boiling down to `obj <=> "str"`. So far this is just Ruby, no Rails. Since `Datetime#<=>` has no special handling for string, it returns nil and story ends here.

In Rails, they redefined [`Datetime#<=>`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) and defined [`String#to_datetime`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-to_datetime)

Comment: Thanks @Siim for the references. What I am wondering about is how the `String.to_datetime` gets automatically invoked? `between?` is a method provided by [Comparable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) module and that method I am invoking on a string. In technical terms the `receiver`, in `Comparable` terms, in my case is a `String` instance which is compared against `another object` which is  `DateTime` instance...

Comment: If I would have been invoking `between?` on `DateTime` instance then it is understood that its redefined `<=>` gets invoked and internally it invokes `to_datetime` on `String` instance to be compared with. As shown in my post Ruby doesn't even allow the comparison against different types and Rails allows it. I checked the Rails augmented behaviour to [String](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/070d4afacd3e9721b7e3a4634e4d026b5fa2c32c/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string.rb) class but I couldn't find in those files where it redefines the behaviour for `<=>` operator.

Comment: Edited the answer, explained how `String#<=>` ends up calling `DateTime#<=>`. Does this help?

Comment: That definitely ends my curiosity. Thanks a lot for you kind help.